# Apache stops working when PHPMyAdmin is being launched

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin

Recently I encountered a problem that when I launch PHPMyAdmin `localhost/phpmyadmin` my apache service just stops working with the message: `Apache HTTP Server has stopped working`.

However, if I simply access my files via `localhost/myapp` everything works just as expected.
In order to gain access to `PHPMyAdmin` all I have to do is restart my apache after it crushed for a few times until somehow it doesn't crush.

I'm using XAMPP Control Panel v3.2.1, Apache 2.4.10, MySQL 5.6.21, PHP 5.6.3, phpMyAdmin 4.2.11.
**OS:** Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit

### EDIT:

If I simply abort the message that says `Apache HTTP Server has stopped working` and don't do anything, apache somehow reset it self and then entering `PHPMyAdmin` without any problem.

Comment: check the Apache logs

Comment: @Dagon It doesn't say anything about crashing. Infact, XAMPP Control Panel still shows that apache is up and running. I just noticed now that If I don't reset my apache, it somehow reset it self alone and accesses `PHPMyAdmin` as expected.

Comment: The Windows event logs may have some info on the crash

Comment: @drew010 After checking windows log I found this: http://pastebin.com/TEyEHyFc Does it mean that my anti-virus (BitDefender) is blocking apache? but how come it doesn't block it when I access `localhost/*`?

Comment: @kfirba That message is exactly what we're looking for and it does seem to indicate the AV is interfering with it for some reason.  The error code 0xc0000005 indicates an access violation.  It's hard to say why accessing phpMyAdmin has that effect but not your main app.  I'd try adding an exclusion to `C:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe` in your AV software so the real time scanner doesn't check that process.

Comment: @drew010 Thanks a lot. It solved the issue. It's still bothering me why it happened only when I accessed `PHPMyAdmin`? Should I close this question or just leave it be? Think about making your comment an answer so I can flag it for future reference.

Comment: Glad it helped, I will add an answer so it may help someone in the future with a similar situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Apache is crashing, the Windows Event Log may have more information about what is causing the crash.

We found the following log:

```
Faulting application name: httpd.exe, version: 2.4.10.0, time stamp: 0x53c79afa
Faulting module name: avcuf32.dll, version: 3.10.9599.5086, time stamp: 0x53fae9cf
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000099f1
Faulting process id: 0x171c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d0083294fee555
Faulting application path: C:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\Bitdefender\Bitdefender 2015\Active Virus Control\Avc3_00270_002\avcuf32.dll
Report Id: d741baff-7425-11e4-a311-1c6f65d4c6e0
```

This indicated the Antivirus software was crashing the Apache process when you try to access phpMyAdmin.

Adding an exclusion to httpd.exe in your AV software may stop it from crashing.

The crash was due to an access violation by BitDefender trying to scan the Apache process.  It's hard to say why only loading phpMyAdmin crashed it and not other apps on your server but it was consistent so possibly a bug in the scanning engine.

Answer (score 0):

Most simple possible solution is to replace all the xampp or wamp server file with new files and pay attention to not replace MYSQL and HTDOCS files. Your problem will be solved effectively. if you replace htdocs and mysql files it will reset your server for new files and your work will not avail for live view. Basically this kind of problem occurs when we make some changes with PHP.ini file or it gets corrupted.  I hope this will resolve your problem.

Comment: This should've been reflected in some kind of logs "Basically this kind of problem occurs when we make some changes with PHP.ini file or it gets corrupted." right? However see the comments , user had a different problem.